# Vertically align TextView text to TextInputLayout text in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, layout, material-design, android-constraintlayout

In a `ConstraintLayout` I have a `TextView` below a `TextInputLayout`. As one can easyily see, the text of the `TextView` starts further left than the text of the `TextInputLayout`. How can I fix this?

This is my current code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />
```

And this is the current result:

design view:

[image]

blue print:

[image]

emulator:

[image]

Comment: Not a solution but you can also try removing `paddingLeft/Start` from edit text using such property : `android:paddingStart="0dp"`.

Comment: I've come across this several times, and it seems to be caused by the background of the `EditText`. If you remove it with `android:background="@null"`, you'll see that the text lines up properly. Unfortunately, this also removes the underline in the `EditText`. If you don't mind a gross hack, you can always remove 3dp from `android:marginStart` on the `EditText` - that also seems to do the trick.

Comment: try android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"

Comment: TextInputLayout or EditText ?

Comment: Have you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

you should try putting the default paddingStart value attribute from the `TextInputLayout` to the `TextView`'s `View`, this will make sure they are always aligned for each device without having to write any constant number

Answer (score 0):

Basically `LinearLayout` is a parent layout of `TextInputLayout` so you can specify negative margin to it.

like below

```
            android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="-4dp"
```

It may solve your problem.